# Load +3 query at time in with click on a button

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

How can I load query +3 at the time? Something like this: 3-6-9?
query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM t_users limit 3*2
```

I want to add this command in a php page and load +3 at the time with a button with this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'script.php',
                success: function(data) {
                    //alert(data);
                    $("p").text(data);

                }
            });
   });
});

</script>
<button type="button">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: you need to keep track of the number of clicks so you parse that to the query. then you need to keep limit as 3 but change the offset to 3* click count

Comment: can you explain more specifically?

Answer (score 0):

you should keep track of the number of clicks in a variable and use that variable inside your query  :

```
let num = 1;
$('button').click((e) => {
   num += 1;

   if(num > 3){
     num = 0;
   }

   $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'script.php',
       data:{
          num
       },
       success: function(data) {
           // process data
       }
   });
 }

 // php
 SELECT * FROM t_users limit 3 offset :num
```

Comment: it doesn't works!i change the ajax script like this but dos'nt work:

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"> num += 1;

   if(num > 3){
     num = 0;
   }
  $(document).ready(function(){
$('button').click((e) => {
   
   $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'script.php',
       data:{
          num
       },
       success: function(data) {
           // process data
       }
   });
 }); 
 });    
</script>